# Definite Integration using properties/fast way to get definite integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I encountered this problem while trying to solve another problem(which I can post if requested) and this step is omitted (perhaps as being trivial) in the solution booklet. 
$$\int_{0}^{1}ln[(1-t)t]dt$$
The answer given is -2,kindly show the steps in arriving at this solution without solving integral!

Edit:
Apologies for not mentioning what all I had tried,the only excuse I have is that it as 3am and I was tired :P.
I tried using KING and QUEEN(after multiplying $(1+t) * t$ inside ln() itself) but the thought of expanding ln() never crossed my mind. Lesson learnt, maths with a sleepy mind is never a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will have more chances to get some help rather than have your questions downvoted (as it happened already) if you show your own work. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you @user539887 for the helpful comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln((1-t)t)\,dt = \int_0^1\ln(1-t)+\ln(t)\,dt=\int_0^1\ln(1-t)\,dt+\int_0^1\ln(t)\,dt$

Use integration by parts to obtain your required answer.